# PHP Error When Submited

Tags: php, error-handling

Im trying to display 2 rows from my database but i want it to be that when i click the 1st row radiobuttons the 1st row updates.. this is not happening ... when i click the 1st row the second row updated .. check it yourself live please ---> http://albsocial.us/seria.php

```
  <?php

 include("connect.php");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 2";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    echo "<h2>Seria A</h2><hr/>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $home = $row['home'];
        $away = $row['away'];
        $win = $row['win'];
        $draw = $row['draw'];
        $lose = $row['lose'];


        echo $home, " - ", $away,"<br/>";

        echo "<form action='' method='post'>

        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>

        <input type='radio' name='select' value='1'>1
        <input type='radio' name='select' value='X'>X
        <input type='radio' name='select' value='2'>2

        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>

        </form>
        ";

         echo $home, " -> ", $win;
         echo "<br/>Barazim  -> ", $draw,"<br/>";
         echo $away, " -> ", $lose,"<hr/>";
    }   

    $id = isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id']:false;

    if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['select'] == 1){
        $select = $_POST['select'];
        $select = $win + $select;
        mysql_query("UPDATE test SET win='$select' WHERE id='$id'");
        header('Location: ../seria.php');
    }else if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['select'] == 'X'){
        $select = $_POST['select'];
        $select = '1';
        $select = $draw + $select;
        mysql_query("UPDATE test SET draw='$select' WHERE id='$id'");
        header('Location: ../seria.php');
    }else if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['select'] == 2){
        $select = $_POST['select'];
        $select = '1';
        $select = $lose + $select;
        mysql_query("UPDATE test SET lose='$select' WHERE id='$id'");
        header('Location: ../seria.php');
    } 

    ?>
```

Comment: Throw in a hidden input with the value of the id?

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop will always leave `$id` set to the id of the last row in your dataset.

You'll need some way of submitting an id for each row in your form. Then, get that value when you retrieve `POST` variables.

If you structure things properly, you won't need to do a header redirect.

Also, I suggest moving the `isset($_POST)` test to it's own if statement, just so none of that code gets executed if nothing has been posted.

Here's how I would rework it:

```php
<?php

include("connect.php");


// if data is submitted, update database
if (!empty($_POST)) {

  $id = isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : false;
  $select = isset($_POST['select'])&&in_array($_POST['select'],array('win','lose','draw')) ? $_POST['select'] : false;

  if ($id && $select) {
    $sql="UPDATE `test` SET `$select`=`$select`+1 WHERE `id`='$id';";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  }

}


// get data from database
$query = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 2";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// output
?><h2>Seria A</h2><hr/><?php

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    ?><p><?=$row['home']?> - <?=$row['away']?></p>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
        <input type="radio" name="select" value="win">1
        <input type="radio" name="select" value="draw">X
        <input type="radio" name="select" value="lose">2
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <p><?=$row['home']?> -> <?=$row['win']?></p>
    <p>Barazim  -> <?=$row['draw']?></p>
    <p><?=$row['away']?> -> <?=$row['lose']?></p><?php

}   


?>
```

Incidentally, how are you handling "home" vs "away" games?

Comment: Hey man thanks for all your help. Where should i include the $id=isset($_POST['id'])&&is_numeric($_POST['id'])?$_POST['id']:false; in every submit if statement that i have?

Comment: Since the `id` will be the same regardless of the value of `$_POST['select']`, I think you should add it only once, just before your first if statement: `if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['select'] == 1){` I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: i included my updated code .. you can check it onlone aswell @showdev at www.albsocial.us/seria.php

Comment: In your method you'd need to select a row before updating it. I've updated my answer with a more streamlined method. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your button name. you should give each of your button name, a different name from each other so that the server will know which form is being submitted. you could try to give your button name based on id like this :

```
<input type='submit' name='submit<?php echo $id; ?>' value='Submit'/>
```

then you could do the conditional statement to see which button is clicked like this :

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit$id'] ) ) { }
```

Comment: This is another method, but it's more difficult to parse the button name to retrieve the id value. Instead you have to create an if statement for each possible button name, which does not seem very scalable.